# How high is multiclass AUROC too high?

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, roc, multi-class

Whenever I get AUROC above 80% for a binary classification problem I do my best to check for leakage and overfitting - and usually my intuition is right, true AUROC is closer to the 70%-75% range.

However I've been working on a multiclass problem for a couple of days and AUROC for any model I produce is always in the 85%-90% range, which just seems a bit too high to be true. This is the first time I'm dealing with real life multiclass problems so it just my be the case that this is expected, but I'd like to be sure and couldn't find any material on how high is too high for multiclass problems.

Comment: This question is way too dependent on the specific application. It's basically impossible to answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking there were reasonable rules of thumb, e.g. the 70% threshold for binary classification problems.

Comment: No as I said this is totally dependent on the application. If you are classifying handwritten digits and have an AUC of 0.99 for identifying, say, 1s, you're below the state of the art. If you can correctly classify if a stock is going to be up or down in 5 minutes with an AUC of 0.5001 you're the richest man on earth (but actually you're probably overfitting already).